# Swift: How to change RTF String without changing the attributes?

Tags: swift, attributes, rtf, appkit

I'm trying to change a large RTF string so I can (by some algorithm) replace any number of characters with the same number of characters but in such a way that the attributes of the characters stays the same.

For example: w**o**rd into w**g**rd. The character `o` was replaced with `g` but it is still bold.

I'm using AppKit and `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Not enough information. Do you replace all o's with g's? If not how do you decide which to change.

Comment: I would replace all kinds of characters, which ones are chosen is decided by an algorithm made by my teacher. All I have access to is the index of the character replaced.

Comment: Get the attributes of the o and set the attributes of the g.